# Motion along circular surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, centripetal-force

The question goes as follows (translated):
An object slides down a circular path with radius $r$ . The object has its maximum speed $v$ when the slope of its trajectory is $α$. Find an expression for the coefficient of friction $μ$ between the object and the surface of the path. Express $μ$ in terms of $r$, $v$ and $α$.

I have added a drawing to make the question clearer
[image]

This is what I understand and have tried:
We know that when the object has reached its max-velocity, the net force in the tangential direction equals $0$:

$\implies m * g * \mathrm{sin}⁡ α  = μ * N$ ($R$ on the drawing)

Next, we know that this is a circular motion. This implies that the acceleration is given by $a =  v^2/r$, and that the net force points twoards the center of rotation.

I believe this implies that $G_x$ must be greater than $N$ (seen from the tangetial perspective), since the net force points towards the center of the circular motion, and $N$ points away from the center. This gives:

$\implies m * g * \mathrm{cos⁡}\ α - N =  m*v^2/r$

However, the solution says this:

$\implies N - m * g * \mathrm{cos} \ ⁡α  = m*v^2/r$

Can someone please explain how the solution can be correct?

Comment: Your drawing shows an object sliding down the "outside" of a circular path.  Could it be that the problem means the object to be sliding down the "inside"?

Comment: I agree with your equation for the diagram, I Guess you misinterpretted the Q

Comment: $v^2/r$ is not a force

Comment: The full solution to determining the speed as a function of the angle and coefficient of friction involves solving a differential equation. It also requires specifying the initial conditions (initial position and velocity). It can be found here:https://www.usna.edu/Users/physics/mungan/_files/documents/Publications/TPT3.pdf Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The “given solution” lets you find $N$ if you know the angle $α$ and $v$.

To find the coefficient of friction, you need the corresponding friction force.  If there is (a variable) friction, then finding $v$ becomes a problem.  To say that the slope of the curve equals $α$ requires an $xy$ system with $+y$ down.  Then $\mathrm{tan} 
 \ α = α$  can be solved for $α$. This problem statement leaves a lot to be desired.